# How to add owlapi to your Visual Studio project as reference?

Tags: c#, .net, ontology

I would like to know how to add owlapi reference in your Visual Studio project.

I know that there is a github repository of it https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi, but I'm not sure how exactly we can download it as a reference in my project.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to implement an OWL API, or connect to an existing service? The project you linked to is Java, not .NET.

Comment: OWL API is a Java library, you can use it via Maven or Gradle references. Search for pre built jars on Maven Central. But if you're using a .net language you'll need some sort of adaptor to use Java libraries.

Comment: Someone is starting to implement OWLAPI in .NET at https://github.com/Ozzard/owlapi.Net; is that what you want? It's really hard to give directions when you won't tell us your destination.

Comment: I see, thank you for the notice.
After searching, I used the dotNetRDF from the NuGet package and works!